# scrape data of different <li> tag and convert them in integer in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to __scrape__a webpage data having two li tag in a ul

```
<ul class="yt-lockup-meta-info"><li>1 year ago</li><li>17,838 views</li></ul>
```

There are many lines like above on the webpage. Following is my code to **scrape** the data.

```
video_data['views'] = [li.get_text().split("<li>") for li in soup.select('ul.yt-lockup-meta-info')]
```

This gives me the following result

```
{'views': [[u'1 year ago344,161 views'], [u'1 year ago205,992 views'], [u'2013'], [u'7 years ago988,833 views'], [u'2 years ago12,911,037 views'], [u'2 years ago136,626 views'], [u'2 years ago8,539,139 views'], [u'1 year ago4,464,589 views'], [u'2 years ago706,493 views'], [u'1 year ago996,555 views'], [u'2 years ago1,267,267 views'], [u'2 years ago557,541 views'], [u'11 months ago27,804 views'], [u'2 years ago4,113,480 views'], [u'2 years ago1,152,996 views'], [u'10 months ago32,867 views'], [u'2 years ago356,698 views'], [u'2 years ago1,040,051 views'], [u'2 years ago8,453,818 views'], [u'View full playlist (15 videos)'], [u'4 months ago104,768 views']]}
```

I want to only get the days and views separately without text and converted to integer. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression
`a` is the `dict`

```
In [7]: for i in a.values()[0]:
    s=re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*', i[0])
    print s
   ....:     
[u'1', u'344,161']
[u'1', u'205,992']
[u'2013']
[u'7', u'988,833']
[u'2', u'12,911,037']
[u'2', u'136,626']
[u'2', u'8,539,139']
[u'1', u'4,464,589']
[u'2', u'706,493']
[u'1', u'996,555']
[u'2', u'1,267,267']
[u'2', u'557,541']
[u'11', u'27,804']
[u'2', u'4,113,480']
[u'2', u'1,152,996']
[u'10', u'32,867']
[u'2', u'356,698']
[u'2', u'1,040,051']
[u'2', u'8,453,818']
[u'15']
[u'4', u'104,768']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [someone has beat you to the punch](https://gist.github.com/shaurz/6796103) already (found via googling "yt-lockup-meta-info").

However, if it's YouTube data you're scraping, you might want to just use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) -- [this API usage example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#retrieve_my_uploads) comes pretty close. :)

Comment: @AKK, Well I know that I can use youtube API but my doubt was regarding scraping. BTW thanx for your reply.